# Significance of differences between two scenarios

Tags: group-differences

CAPTCHAs are used to distinguish legitimate human users from computerized programs that are trying to abuse online services. There is a way to bypass the security by relaying CAPTCHA challenges to remote human-solvers via crowdsourcing techniques.

A study was conducted. Four types of CAPTCHAs were solved by (1) legitimate human users, (2) human users after the CAPTCHA was streamed to their computer and their answer was collected (simulating the effect of a program relaying the CAPTCHA to crowdsourcing workers and then collecting the responses).

How could the significance of differences of completion time between the two scenarios (1) and (2) across the 4 different CAPTCHAs be analyzed?

Comment: Suggest you think in simpler terms:  how might time differences be analyzed in some routine situation where there are two conditions to be compared and where an independent variable can take on 4 values in each condition?

Comment: Can you do some designed experiment where you know the conditions, and know the correct assignment of situation for each data point?  Then, based on that, we could build a discrimination model (or see if such is going to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could use ANOVA to analyze your data. (Anova stands for analysis of variance.)  But, if you need a statistical test to detect meaningful differences, then the differences may be too small to be of practical usefulness.  Why not start out with simple data summaries, such as means, standard deviations, and plots.  If you cannot notice sizeable differences, looking for small differeneces using statistical tests may or may not be helpful to you, depending on what you are planning to do based on your conclusions.

Comment: Response/waiting times are probably not close to normally distributed, but we could use the idea behind anova within some generalized linear model (maybe with gamma distributed variables?).

Comment: Checking the distribution is a good idea if you are going to conduct a statistical test.  It might be a good idea in any case.  Sometimes differences in variance or other measures are as important or more important as a differences in means.